# Java xpath parsing unable to parse correctly

Tags: java, xpath, html-parsing, htmlcleaner

I wrote a small code for parsing html pages using xpath. My problem is that this code works for some pages and does not work for other one. Would you please guide me what possibly caused such problem? I did some debug and my first guess is that I did not properly use Html cleaner.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        try {
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1", readDocument(),
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
    private static Document readDocument() throws IOException {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(
                "http://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com/medical-team-asks-obese-saudi-wait-death-home-072857829.html");
        java.net.URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();
        props.setTranslateSpecialEntities(true);
        props.setTransResCharsToNCR(true);
        props.setOmitComments(true);

        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(reader);
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);
            return doc;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This code should extract the text inside xpath pattern and simply print that. But in the required example does not work.

Solution: I found out that the problem caused by the fact that I used absolute xpath and probably this time of xpath can be changed after compiling html page in browser. The main problem solved by using relative xpath but I can not reach to some parts of html using relative xpath and I need to use absolute one. So my question would be how can I use the compile version of html in my java code?

Comment: Can you add some more detail around "doesnt work"?

Comment: Does not extract the specific content related to xpath pattern. I am sure that the xpath pattern is right. For example for the mentioned example nodes.lenght()=0 so it would not print anything!

Comment: well, obviously your XPath is not correct for your data, if you do not get back any result. Your XPath looks very much like you find it using some XPath browser tool and simply copied it. As your browser parses a web page, it could very well be that the structure is different for for Java connection. Try a more basic XPath and show if this returns any result.

Comment: Xpath is correct. I use firefox firebug addon to extract them. I did use other tools same xpath was found. I should mention that same process works for some websites. If it was due to xpath it should not work for all websites!

Comment: The xpath was correct but it was the absolute xpath and I fount out that I should use relative xpath to handle this situation.

Comment: @Alin Please use the @ syntax, otherwise people will not get notifications for your comments. Your statement, however, is not true. It can very well be that firebug produces an xpath for one element, which you can use in your program and it works and for another one it doesn't - This is due to the fact that Browsers change the HTML DOM, e.g. tables are quite well-known for this, whereby the browser automatically inserts <tbody> elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your XPath isn't working that means that your selector cannot be found in the document. When you look a the article in your browsers sometimes things aren't always as they seem. Remember that when you look at it in the browser JavaScript is being executed and many times that means rearranging or adding elements to the DOM.

Your XPath query is a bit specific and you might have better luck making it a bit more relaxed so if one `<div>` tag is missing it wont break the entire thing. Expecially when using xpaths in HTML you should rely more on the `id` and `class` attributes. I think your trying to get the page title which is directly under the element with id `mediaarticlehead`.

Using this xpath `//*[@id="mediaarticlehead"]/div/h1`.

However all this to get a article title when the W3C already solved this problem with `<meta>` tags :). Check out in the `<head>` of the document and you will find the title, description and likely a link to an image for the article.

Comment: Unfortunately all pages do not have meta tag for title, image and etc.